Unable to use an Object's property in templates when imported from a different class
I am new to angular and i am facing issue where Angular16 does not display the properties of an object when defined in an external class. Check out the following illustration.
I have defined a class in the following manner. I use this class to store data i receive from the backend. These values are reused in other components.
export class StaticClass {
    static dict:{[key: string]: Array<object> } = {
        1: [],
        2: [
            { id: 1, text: "Hello" },
        ],
        3: [],
}}

I then import this class to use the values stored.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StaticClass } from 'src/app/utils/calendarEvents';

@Component({ ..<omitted>.. })
export class SampleViewComponent {
    staticClass = StaticClass;
    temp = [{ id: 1, text: "Hello" }]


   constructor(){
        console.log(this.staticClass.dict[2])
        console.log(this.temp)
    }
}

Here, both console outputs displays the same thing.
However, TS throws me an error when i try to display the values in staticClass.
<div *ngFor="let i of this.staticClass.dict[2]">
    {{ i.id }}
</div>

Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'.ngtsc(2339)
But it works just fine when using temp.
<div *ngFor="let i of this.temp">
    {{ i.id }}
</div>

Questions:

How can we rectify the above issue? What is different between temp and staticClass.dict[2]
Is there a better way to store the values i receive from backend? Since these are going to be temporary and changing throughout, i don't want to use browser local storage.


In the Stack Overflow community, we don't encourage asking multiple questions within the same post unless the questions are linked. So your Q2 which asks for how to store the data in Angular app should be in different post, not the same post for your main question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402523/do-we-really-need-more-focus

Hi @YongShun Noted. Thanks

The difference between the values:

in the StaticClass: Defined as Array<object> type.

for the temp variable: Defined as { id: number; text: string; }[].


Even though in common, we understand that both of them are arrays of objects, but the compiler treats them differently. The object implements/extends the Object interface. For your reference: 'any' vs 'Object'
If you know the structure of your object and it is consistent (same structure applied to all objects), you can define the type as:
export class StaticClass {
  static dict: { [key: string]: Array<{id: number; text: string}> } = {
    1: [],
    2: [{ id: 1, text: 'Hello' }],
    3: [],
  };
}

Or you can work with any so that the compiler skips the type-checking.
export class StaticClass {
  static dict: { [key: string]: Array<any> } = {
    1: [],
    2: [{ id: 1, text: 'Hello' }],
    3: [],
  };
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

Hi @Yong Shun, Thanks a ton. This helped. So its better to define the type of array or let it just be any.
Is there any use case where defining the type as Array is useful?

As I know that the object type is used when attempting to check the value is non-primitive: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type

@Yong Shun already gave a correct answer. Even though I would highly recommend to make use of the full feature-set of typescript by using types/interfaces.
This can be achieved like this:
staticclass.ts
export interface Parent {
  [key: string]: Array<Something>;
}

export interface Something {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  additionalInfo?: string; // optional parameter
}

export class StaticClass {
  static dict: Parent = {
    1: [],
    2: [{ id: 1, text: 'Hello' }],
    3: [{ id: 5, text: 'asf', additionalInfo: 'great product!' }],
    // 4: [{ id: 5, txt: 'asf'}], // ❌ typo in 2nd parameter would throw TS-error
  };

By this (a) type-errors can be found when compiling (b) some user of your components knows what kind of data he can expect.
my.component.ts
@Component({
  /* ... */
  templateUrl: `my.component.template.html`,
})
export class App {
  dict: Parent = StaticClass.dict; // ✅ dev sees whats going on on first sight
}

my.component.template.html
@for(i of this.dict[2]; track i.id) {
    {{ i.id }} <!-- ✅ dev knows id exists without checking StaticClass -->
}

Stackblitz


Try to use ! to avoid object not initiated error.

<div *ngFor="let i of this.temp">
    {{ i!.id! }}
</div>

